# TextOut() - "invalid null pointer"

Tags: c++, pointers, null

I've written a program in C++ which is displaying a white window.
Furthermore I'm displaying a text in the window. To accomplish this purpose,
I use the `TextOut()`-Function. It's working,
but besides the displayed sentence, the following is displayed:

```
invalid null pointer (__onexitbegin != NULL && __onexitend != NULL)||(__onexitbegin == NULL && __onexitend == NULL)
```

After this error there are lots of chinese signs.
I researched on the internet but havn't found anything useful yet.

This is the code I'm using to display the text:

```
const wchar_t* string = L"This is a test.";
hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, string, 500); //the length is just for test purpose
EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling [`TextOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that the length of the string is 500 characters when it is really only 15 characters. Since [`TextOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not stop at a null terminator it will draw exactly how many characters you tell it to. The extra text, garbage, and Chinese characters you are seeing is other data that is stored *after* the string literal `"This is a test."`.